# document.getElements() support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, jsfiddle

How well supported is the document.getElements() function. Additionally, is there a javascript reference page that has detailed browser support information somewhere. I usually use the mozilla docs, but I was wondering if there is something better.

I actually can't find any documentation on document.getElements() but when I do things like:

document.getElements("div a");

It works great in chrome, ff, safari, ie8 and ie6-9 via IETester. I think IETester may use the same javascript engine for all browsers though (not sure about that).

Comment: What versions of Chrome and Firefox are you running? I tested that line in both Chrome and Firefox and both report that window.document has no member called "getElements".

Comment: Are you studying the getElements() method specifically or trying to get DOM elements within different browsers? If it's the latter case, why not use javascript libraries such as jQuery?

Comment: I am running Firefox 3.6.14pre and Chromium 7.0.517.44 on Linux, and I am not finding any such function. I agree with Bryan; use a library such as jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: I use jquery all the time and really like it. I just did a "for in" on the document object and stumbled upon getElements() had never heard of it - guessed what it was and was curious about browser support. So I'm really just curious - especially because google turns up nothing on it at all...

Comment: @BryanShen Because they will be deprecated as IE7 dies and document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll are given more attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as document.getElements... I'll bet your coding in Jsfiddle and don't realize that the mootools lib is included ;)

Have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/pRKzy/

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that. Hilarious.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for [`querySelecterAll` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
elementList = parentNode.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

This is most handy and much usable function.

To check how your requested feature is supported among browsers you can use ["Can I Use" site](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll):

```
https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll
```

On this site you can check not only functions but HTML attributes and CSS capabilities too

Answer (score 0):

[quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) is a pretty good resource for things like this (though not fully updated on IE9, as it's a moving target at the moment).

Note: they don't have an entry for `document.getElements()` specifically (are you sure you're getting this name right?), but in general it's a pretty complete reference, [here's an example](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) - check out [`.querySelectorAll()`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13) (which does what you describe...).

Comment: cool thanks. I was aware of queryselectorAll() part of the reason I was shocked when document.getElements() worked in IE6... although like I said I think IETester might not be a good way to test javascript.