# Get text of a span using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code for generating select box by getting value from `ul li` menu.

html menu:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>
   <a class="menu-item active parent" href="#">
    <span class="menu">
    <span class="menu-title">Inspiration</span>
    <span class="menu-desc">wow! Amazing </span>
    </span>
   </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get only `<span class="menu-title">` text. my current javascript code gets text from both span.
here is javascript:

```
document.getElements('ul.menu a.menu-item').each(function (el) {
            optText = '&nbsp;' + el.get('text');
```

**NOTE:**  I can get text from the first span changing this `getElements('ul.menu a.menu-item')` to this `getElements('ul.menu a.menu-item span.menu-title')` but then some of my code will not work. So please change the second line

`optText = '&nbsp;' + el.get('text');`

Comment: [Are you suing mootools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363036/document-getelements-support)

Comment: I hope he's Using mootools, not suing them...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an external library? I do not understand your javascript.

To get the contents of "menu-title", you would use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title")[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: Actually, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array.  So you would probably need something like `document.getElementsByClassName("menu-title")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Is that not what you wanted? You state "I want to get only <span class="menu-title"> text. my current javascript code gets text from both span."

Comment: please change this code only `optText = '&nbsp;' + el.get('text');`. I have already the element `document.getElements('ul.menu a.menu-item').each(function (el) {
`

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, I simply changed this;

```
optText = '&nbsp;' + el.get('text');
```

to:

```
optText = '&nbsp;' + el.getElements('span.menu-title').get('text');
```

anyway! friends thanks for help